# How do I write a regex match to a file each on a line using python?

Tags: python, regex

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as output:
    for file in glob.glob('*.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r', encoding="latin-1") as f:
            for line in f:
                pattern = r"justwhatever"
                find = re.findall(pattern, line)
                try:
                    output.write('\n'.join(find[0:])+'\n')
                except UnicodeEncodeError:
                    pass
```

This has kept me up all night, I'm trying to search through big text files, my code crashes due to poor memory, I tried going through it line by line as you see in my code above, but I just can't seem to print each result on a separate line.

I'm able to either write add an "\n" to each searched line, which leaves me with many blank lines, or have all the result stacked together and only get separate lines once there's more than just one result on the same line ...

How would I go about searching my files line by line and outputing only the search match when it occurs on a line of it's own ?

Comment: `if line == "justwhatever\n"` would do what you are asking. Why do you need a regex? Why do you need to print the line if you already know what it contains?

Comment: This is just a simplified code, my regex is a bit more complicated, and the lines doesn't only include the regex, they're pretty long.
Your code only outputs an empty text file since the lines have more words.

Comment: Even tried `if r"justwhatever" in line:` and is still gave me an empty file

Comment: Then what does "[outputting] only the search match when it occurs on a line of [its] own" mean?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't get to test it on your files but I tried it on this [file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlafeldt/google-python-class/master/basic/alice.txt). This should work.

```
import glob, re
with open('output.txt', 'a') as output:
    for file in glob.glob('alice.txt'):
        with open(file, 'r') as f:
            for line in f.readlines():
                pattern = r"Alice"
                find = re.findall(pattern, line)
                if find:
                    try:
                        output.write(' '.join(find[0:])+'\n')
                    except UnicodeEncodeError:
                        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found this:

```
for line in f:
                pattern = r"yourpattern"
                find = re.search(pattern, line)
                if find:
                    try:
                        output.write(find.group() + '\n')
                    except UnicodeEncodeError:
                        pass
```

which works, but very slowly, hope someone got a better code for this to parse faster

Comment: What does "very slowly" mean? I don't think there is an easy way of optimizing this, but it should be reasonably fast for a simple pattern. My suspicion goes to an inefficient regex, but you are apparently not showing us the real thing. Look up "catastrophic backtracking".

Comment: In theory, you might want to compile the regex outside the loop; but if it's a static regex, the Python regex engine notices that it has already compiled this before, and reuses the result from its internal cache.